# How to open many URL in one view (IOS - Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I am building a "About Us" view on IOS app and on my "About Us", it will link to many profiles of myself.

The link initially would work. But if I quit safari and go back to my app, other link will not work. Here, I have to reload this view again by going back to last view and navigate back to "About Us" view again.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func monicalink(sender: UIButton) {

    if( sender.currentImage! == UIImage(named:"twitter_f.png")){
        print(sender)
        safari.openURL(NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/lalaphoon")!)
    }
    else if (sender.currentImage! == UIImage(named:"github_f.png")) {

        safari.openURL(NSURL(string: "https://github.com/lalaphoon")!)

    }
    //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    // viewDidLoad()
}
```

I tried to reload the view (calling `viewDidLoad`) after having clicked the button. But it won't work. Any suggestions or help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using SFSafariViewController?

Comment: No. it's just a simple UIApplication.sharedApplication(),usually people do this: UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://example.com")).

Comment: Sorry I didn't write clearly. I wrote this before:     let safari = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

Comment: Well, I can see one problem with your code. You can't use `==` to compare two `UIImage`s since they'll be in different memory even if they have the same underlying image. You should use an `Int`, let's say `currentImageIndex` to track which one is currently chosen. Also, do you actually update `currentImage` when user taps on the image?

Comment: No, button's currentImage won't be changed after a user click that button.

Comment: I looked at this webpage http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-sfsafariviewcontroller--cms-24260, which might talk about this issue in the first example. I'm not sure about this too much.I think i will try the third example.

Comment: I need more codes to see what problem you're having. But comparing two `UIImage`s will not work.

Comment: I used the third way on that website and it's working. Would you mind to talk about more about `currentImageIndex` ?